# need to display hard error , transport error & soft errors above 2

Tags: shell-script, solaris

```
iostat -En | nawk '/Hard Errors/ {line=$0;gsub(/.*Hard Errors:/,""); \
                                  if($1>2) printf("%s\n",line); }'
```

The output of this is

```
c0t1d0          Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 5 Transport Errors: 0
```

But in my case I need to display the output like this:

```
warning about iostat hard error , transport error & soft errors > 2 on system1 is \
"c0t1d0          Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 5 Transport Errors: 0".
```

But not only in Hard Error case but if any of the errors above 2 (hard error, transport error & soft errors) need to display.

Comment: Could you clarify the case: you need to print if (transport error+soft errors>0) or (transport error>0 & soft errors>0), but do you need a warning if (Hard Errors>2) and "transport error & soft errors > 2"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
$ iostat -En | nawk '/Hard Errors:/{if($4>2 || $7>2 || $10){
   print "Iostat warning on system1, hard, soft or transfer errors > 2:\n"$0}}'
```

Since the Linux version of `iostat` does not have the `-E` or `-n` options, I can't check this. If it doesn't do what you want, please post the output of your `iostat` command so I can see what to parse.

Comment: On my Solaris 11.x system, your oneliner works well for me:

`# iostat -En | nawk '/Hard Errors:/{if($4>2 || $7>2 || $10){
>    print "Iostat warning on system1, hard, soft or transfer errors > 2:\n"$0}}'`

Iostat warning on system1, hard, soft or transfer errors > 2:

c5t50024E90037AF38Cd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 4128 Transport Errors: 0 

Iostat warning on system1, hard, soft or transfer errors > 2:

c5t50024E90037AF390d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 4128 Transport Errors: 0